# Generate a date vector wherein all years are formatted as leap years R

Tags: r, date, leap-year

How can I get the correct dates using the following information:

`All years are formatted as leap years with 29 days for February and Julian day 60 are missing in the no-leap years`?

My `rasterstack` has length (nlayers) =23376 and I want to add a record dimension from 1950-01-01 to 2013-12-31. So I tried to generate a date vector like this:

`dates=seq(as.POSIXct("1950-01-01 "), as.POSIXct("2013-12-31"), by="day")`

but all years are not as described above and `length(dates)`=23375.

Thanks for your suggestions.
AT.

Comment: Well, you're doing better than me, because I get `23012` days - `table(format(dates,"%Y"))` shows the leap years having the correct `366` day counts. Are you sure you don't mean `dates <- seq(as.POSIXct("1950-01-01 "), as.POSIXct("2013-12-31"), by="day")` which has a length of `23376`?

Comment: @thelatemail   sorry I meant `dates=seq(as.POSIXct("1950-01-01 "), as.POSIXct("2013-12-31"), by="day")`. I have edited my question. How did you get length of 23376? When I run the above I get 23375 instead of 23376 which is the number of `layers in my rasterstack`. Apart from generating the date, does the date vector satisfy the condition: `All years are formatted as leap years with 29 days for February and Julian day 60 are missing in the no-leap years`? This will ensure that I am assigning the right dates to different values in my timeseries. Thanks.

Comment: `table(format(dates,"%Y"))` shows 2013 to have 364 days instead?

Comment: Definitely `365` days in 2013 over here too.

Comment: This what I got: > table(format(dates,"%Y"))
`...
 365  365  366  365  365  365  366  365  365  365  366  365  365  365  366  365  365  365  366  365  365 
1971 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977 1978 1979 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 
 365  366  365  365  365  366  365  365  365  366  365  365  365  366  365  365  365  366  365  365  365 
1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 
 366  365  365  365  366  365  365  365  366  365  365  365  366  365  365  365  366  365  365  365  366 
2013 
 364`

Comment: I can only suggest you do `seq(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2013-12-31"), by="day")` and see what day is missing to give a hint as to what is going wrong.

Comment: I get 23376 for the length of that vector. Is this some weird timezone thing?

Comment: @42 Do u mean you get 23376 using length(dates)= 23376? I keep getting 23375 after testing my code on two PCs.

Comment: `> tail(dates)
[1] "2013-12-25 01:00:00 CST" "2013-12-26 01:00:00 CST" "2013-12-27 01:00:00 CST" "2013-12-28 01:00:00 CST"
[5] "2013-12-29 01:00:00 CST" "2013-12-30 01:00:00 CST"`;
`> head(dates)
[1] "1950-01-01 MST" "1950-01-02 MST" "1950-01-03 MST" "1950-01-04 MST" "1950-01-05 MST" "1950-01-06 MST"`. You see that Dec 2013 has 30 instead of 31 days that is why i am getting 23375 days instead of 23376. This is really weird.
>

Comment: You should be using `as.Date` rather than `as.POSIXct`.

Comment: @42 as.Date did the magic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following suggestions from the @thelatemail and @42 I got the right dates by using:

```
dates=seq(as.Date("1950-01-01"), as.Date("2013-12-31"), by="day")
> length(dates)
[1] 23376
> table(format(dates,"%Y"))
```

Using `as.POSIXct` did not give me the complete dates:

```
dates=seq(as.POSIXct("1950-01-01 "), as.POSIXct("2013-12-31"), by="day")
```